# Burn [dlc] as per Cleanup Thread 2013/14

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags, burnination

As [discussed on last/this years tag burnination question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7951/28182)*, [dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) should be burned outright.

Mods, please remove one of the last vestiges of the ambiguous tag era!

<sub>* Or rather, not discussed as everyone who has seen it over the last 3 months has either agreed or not cared enough to downvote/argue for its continued existence.)</sub>

Comment: Where do I find the actual discussion regarding [dlc]? Seems strange that such an obvious clarifier has been burned.

Comment: @l0b0 - It was deleted from the linked question after the tag had been removed. The reasons for the deletion were: 1) It's a Type 3 tag (ambiguous), 2) Questions about DLC in relation to a game should have the game tag, 3) Questions relating to DLC installation or downloading from respective stores or sites should use the system tag (and troubleshooting questions should have the technical-issues tag
4) If the DLC is a large enough topic area to warrant its own tag, it should be split off the main game tag as some already are (eg [tag:skyrim-dawnguard])

Comment: Also: See the discussions that took place even earlier than that [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/should-questions-about-a-games-dlc-be-tagged-with-the-individual-name-of-the-dlc?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dlc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlc) has been removed from all questions where it appeared.